# action parameter not populated by fluid form

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

Hello all I have trouble providing an object filled in a form to a an action: I'm able to load the form and populate it using the object prepared in the showing action but when I submit it to the form to store the object the form content is not passed in the action method parameter , but instead is in an array in the request arguments. So it seems the model class is correct, the form is correct and the first action is correct, but either there is something missing in the fluid form or something is wrong in the action. Any suggestion on what to look for as cause of the issue? Thanks in advance. 
This is the controller that loads the form

```
/**
 * @param \Aip\AipMediakey\Domain\Model\Subscriptions $newSubscription
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\NoSuchArgumentException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\StopActionException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\UnsupportedRequestTypeException
 */
public function iscrizioneAwardFirstStepAction(\Aip\AipMediakey\Domain\Model\Subscriptions $newSubscription = NULL)
{
.....
        $newSubscription = $this->objectManager->get('Aip\AipMediakey\Domain\Model\Subscriptions');
        /** @var \Aip\AipMediakey\Domain\Model\Subscriptions $newSubscription */
        $newSubscription->setCampaignTitle('');
        $newSubscription->setProductName('');

        $this->view->assign('newSubscription', $newSubscription);


.....
```

This is the fluid form

```
<f:form action="iscrizioneAwardStepSoggetti" object="{newSubscription}" name="newSubscription" >
    <f:form.hidden property="eventId"  value="{award.uid}"/>

    Iscrizione all'award : {award.title}

    Campagna <br>
    Titolo Campagna <f:form.textfield property="campaignTitle" /> <br>
    NomeProdotto <f:form.textfield property="productName" /> <br>

   <f:form.button  type="submit" name="Indietro" value="indietro" formmethod="post">Indietro</f:form.button>
    <f:form.button  type="submit" name="Procedi" value="procedi" formmethod="post">Procedi</f:form.button>


</f:form>
```

This the action that is called submitting the form:

```
/**
 * @param \Aip\AipMediakey\Domain\Model\Subscriptions $newSubscription
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\StopActionException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\UnsupportedRequestTypeException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Exception\IllegalObjectTypeException
 */
public function IscrizioneAwardStepSoggettiAction(\Aip\AipMediakey\Domain\Model\Subscriptions $newSubscription = NULL)
{


        $this->subscriptionsRepository->add($newSubscription);


}
```

Comment: Is the capital first char in the function `IscrizioneAwardStepSoggettiAction` by accident? A function should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Yes I had discovered it yesterday.... I have several action in that controller all named correclty but I was overlooking that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake, the method

IscrizioneAwardStepSoggettiAction

should have been named

iscrizioneAwardStepSoggettiAction (starting i in lowercase)

as stated in ext_local_conf.php

I hope at least this answer can help someone else.